# Can I print pandas dataframe with color in some grid?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame, I want to highlight some data.

for example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(range(25), (5,5)))

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
```

I want to make data `df[4] > 15` highlighted(color Red). that's 19 and 24

I am using linux terminal.

How Can I realize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `termcolor` library, which automatically formats strings so that they display text colors or background colors in terminal.

However, this will modify the actual values in column `4` of your DataFrame, which is why I made a copy of your original DataFrame purely for the purpose of printing in terminal. For example, the value `19` will become the string `'\x1b[41m19\x1b[0m'`.

I also formatted the background color of the other values in column 4 so that when they are printed, they are aligned with the values with a red background - if this isn't done, they will be aligned with the column number. You can modify the parameter `'on_white'` to match your background color in terminal.

You can also align the column name by modifying the column name `4`.

```
from termcolor import colored
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(range(25), (5,5)))
df_print = df.copy()
df_print[4] = [colored(str(x), None, 'on_red') if x>15 else colored(str(x), None, 'on_white') for x in df_print[4]]
df_print.columns = [0,1,2,3] + [colored('4', None, 'on_white')]
```

[image]

Here are the underlying values in the `print_df` DataFrame:

```
>>> df_print.values
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, '\x1b[47m4\x1b[0m'],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, '\x1b[47m9\x1b[0m'],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, '\x1b[47m14\x1b[0m'],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, '\x1b[41m19\x1b[0m'],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, '\x1b[41m24\x1b[0m']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: thanks Derek, but print(df_print) seems not aligned

Comment: @nick i've modifyed the column name `4` so that it's also aligned with the column values

Comment: No problem, glad my answer was helpful!

Comment: align all cols using `df_print.columns = [colored(x, 'white', None) for x in df_print.columns]`

Comment: How to do that for multiple selected columns(let's say Col1,Col3, Col4)with multiple colour choices(red for first largest values, green for second largest values and yellow for third largest values in above selected columns individually.